# Multiple pods and nodes management in Kubernetes

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I've been digging the Kubernetes documentation to try to figure out what is the recommend approach for this case.

I have a private movie API with the follow microservices (pods).

```
- summary
- reviews
- popularity
```

Also I have accounts that can access these services.

1. How do restrict access to services per account e.g. account A can access all the services but account B can only access `summary`.
2. The account A could be doing 100x more requests than account B. It's possible to scale services for specific accounts?
3. Should I setup the accounts as Nodes?

I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Any thoughts or animated gifs are very welcome.

Comment: If you want to control the  operations or actions on provided resources, RBAC is the way to authorize the users or service accounts

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is level of control should be implemented at the application level.

Access to particular parts of your application, in this case the services, should probably be controlled via user permissions. Similar line of thought for scaling out the services...allow everything to scale but rate limit up front, e.g., account A can get 10 requests per second and account B can do 100x. Designating accounts to nodes might also be possible, but should be avoided. You don't want to end up micromanaging the orchestration layer :)